# How do register_sidebar() and get_sidebar() work together?

Tags: customization, themes, theme-development, widgets

***Disclaimer:*** I am brand spanking new to WP.

I am using the [Starkers HTML5 framework theme](http://nathanstaines.com/archive/starkers-html5-v3). In the `functions.php` I see this code:

```
function starkers_widgets_init() {

  // Area 1, located at the top of the sidebar.
  register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Primary Widget Area', 'starkers' ),
    'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
    'description' => __( 'The primary widget area', 'starkers' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li>',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

  // Area 3, located in the footer. Empty by default.
  register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'First Footer Widget Area', 'starkers' ),
    'id' => 'first-footer-widget-area',
    'description' => __( 'The first footer widget area', 'starkers' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li>',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

  // ... more calls to register_sidebar() ... 
}
```

And in `footer.php` I see this code:

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>
```

I don't understand how `get_sidebar()` knows how to take that string argument and find the appropriate widgets that were defined by `register_sidebar()`.  In the functions.php snippet I posted above. There isn't any mention of "footer" except for the `name`, `id` and `description` properties. But it would seem odd to me that `get_sidebar()` would search for 'footer' inside those properties.

Does this make sense what I am asking? Is there some missing piece?

The reasons I am asking is because
 - I would like to know more about the WP architecture
 - I would like to be able to define a custom widget area and know how to render it on a specific page.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just call [`get_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) from `index.php` and it loads the theme file `sidebar.php`.

[`register_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar), on the other hand, is used for widgets where plugins and such want to dynamically add content in your `sidebar.php` file if your theme supports it.

In your case, is there a file called `sidebar-footer.php` in your theme's directory?

Answer (score 11):

I've never bothered with `get_sidebar()`. Instead I just use `dynamic_sidebar()`. You'd call it like this:

```
dynamic_sidebar('first-footer-widget-area');
```

And that takes care of the whole sidebar. No more file inclusions, no more cluttered theme folders. If I want to have 5 different sidebars, it doesn't add any files, only extra functions in `functions.php`.

Comment: In the case of Starkers, `sidebar-footer.php` conditionally calls `dynamic_sidebar()` for all the appropriate widget areas.

Comment: That may be true, but if you know the version you're running, there's no need to conditionally call it, and why run an include if you can just call the function directly?

Answer (score 6):

`get_sidebar('name')` gets a sidebar template of the name `sidebar-name.php`
.

Within sidebar-name.php, there is the HTML for the sidebar, and a call to `dynamic_sidebar('some-name-hopefully-the-same')`, which is where the widgets will go.

`register_sidebar(array(name=>'some-name-hopefully-the-same', ...))` is what allows dynamic_sidebar to work.

As you can see, `get_sidebar(templatename)` is for use with sidebar-templates.  If you have no need for them, you can just call `dynamic_sidebar(sidebarname)` directly from your theme.

Answer (score 3):

`get_sidebar('footer')` attempts to load `sidebar-footer.php` from the active theme. Starkers does provide this file. Check `starkers/sidebar-footer.php` and things should become clear.