# What is the difference with get_sidebar and dynamic_sidebar?

Tags: sidebar

What is the difference with `get_sidebar()` and `dynamic_sidebar()`?

I was wondering which one I should use. Maybe one use widgets and the other one doesn't?

Comment: Have you read the [**`get_sidebar()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) and [**`dynamic_sidebar()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) Codex entries?

Comment: This question is useful as the difference is not clear at all after reading the WP documentation twice…

Comment: Having just read through some docs and a tutorial, I *still* had to view an example and do some detective work.  Nothing ambiguous about the question at all.  Please see my answer in a more specific and cluttered but essentially the same question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/500/how-do-register-sidebar-and-get-sidebar-work-together/202335#202335

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please refer to the [**`get_sidebar()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar/) and [**`dynamic_sidebar()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dynamic_sidebar/) Codex entries.

The `get_sidebar( $slug )` template tag includes the `sidebar-$slug.php` template-part file.

The `dynamic_sidebar( $slug )` template tag outputs the `$slug` dynamic sidebar, as defined by `register_sidebar( array( 'id' => $slug ) )`.

Comment: so....what's the difference?

Comment: `get_sidebar` always looks for a template file.

`dynamic_sidebar` only looks for the associated `register_sidebar` details and `widgets` configured in `wp-admin`

Comment: `get_sidebar(templatename)` is for loading a sidebar-template of the name `'sidebar-templatename.php'`, which would have `dynamic_sidebar(sidebarname)` in it.  If you don't need the template, you can place dynamic_sidebar directly in your theme or other area.  Beware, get_sidebar contains hooks that won't get called if it isn't used.